# Por que posso editar perguntas deletadas de outras pessoas?

Tags: suporte, bug, edição

Eu esbarrei nesta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/180750/revisions (observe o histórico), e ela estava deletada na hora que eu a vi. No entanto, havia um erro de formatação nela e vi que o link de editar continuava disponível. Então pensei: "***Será que posso editar uma pergunta deletada de outra pessoa?***", fiz o teste e descobri que posso sim, a pergunta foi editada por mim enquanto ela estava deletada.

A autora da pergunta a restaurou após a minha edição.

Agora, pergunto: Isso é esperado? Esse comportamento é intencional? Editar perguntas deletadas por outras pessoas sem ser moderador é algo válido a se fazer ou é uma forma de abusar das ferramentas de edição disponibilizadas?

Comment: Por que seria um abuso da ferramenta de edição? Entendo que se está deletada, o máximo que você terá talvez é perdido tempo, ainda mais se o autor não tiver intenção de restaurar. Não vejo como muito prejudicial isso, até porque o histórico de revisão continua la, mesmo após deletada(já me assustei com gente editando o proprio post deletado tambem hehe)

Comment: Não posso ver perguntas deletadas muito menos edita-las então não há muito para dizer, então eu diria que isso me parece ser válido sim, algumas perguntas deletadas ainda podem ser salvas.